# How to hide Material-Ui Mini variant Drawer on mobile view

Tags: material-design, material-ui

How can I hide Mini variant drawer on mobile view. I don't want the side bar on mobile view. It should be hidden in mobile view.

I am following the official doc [Original Code](https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/)

[image: Mini Variant Drawer]

Remove in mobile View

[image: Remove in mobile view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const drawerWidth = 240;
    
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
  },
  toolbarIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  menuButtonHidden: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: 'relative',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      position: 'relative',
    },
  },
  drawerPaperClose: {
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    width: theme.spacing.unit * 7,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 9,
    },
  },
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    height: '100vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
  chartContainer: {
    marginLeft: -22,
  },
  tableContainer: {
    height: 320,
  },
});

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    auth: true,
    anchorEl: null,
  };

  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ auth: event.target.checked });
  };

  handleMenu = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, siteTitle, children,theme } = this.props;
    const { auth, anchorEl } = this.state;
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <AppBar
            position="absolute"
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, this.state.open && classes.appBarShift)}
            style={{ background: '#051745', boxShadow: 'none' }}
          >
            <Toolbar disableGutters={!this.state.open} className={classes.toolbar}>
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="Open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                className={classNames(
                  classes.menuButton,
                  this.state.open && classes.menuButtonHidden,
                )}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.title}>
                {siteTitle}
              </Typography>
              <IconButton color="inherit">
                <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                  <NotificationsIcon />
                </Badge>
              </IconButton>
              <div>
                <IconButton
                  aria-owns={open ? 'menu-appbar' : null}
                  aria-haspopup="true"
                  onClick={this.handleMenu}
                  color="inherit"
                >
                  <AccountCircle />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                  id="menu-appbar"
                  anchorEl={anchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'right',
                  }}
                  transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'right',
                  }}
                  open={open}
                  onClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
              </div>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>

          <Hidden mdUp>
          <Drawer
            variant="temporary"
            onClose={this.handleDrawerClose}
            classes={{
              paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, !this.state.open && classes.drawerPaperClose),
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
            open={this.state.open}
          >
            <div className={classes.toolbarIcon}>
              {siteTitle}
              <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            <Divider />
            <List >{mainListItems}</List>
            <Divider />
            <List>{secondaryListItems}</List>
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden smDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            variant="permanent"
            classes={{
              paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, !this.state.open && classes.drawerPaperClose),
            }}
            open={this.state.open}
          >
            <div className={classes.toolbarIcon}>
              {siteTitle}
              <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            <Divider />
            <List >{mainListItems}</List>
            <Divider />
            <List>{secondaryListItems}</List>
          </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
          <main className={classes.content} >
            <div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />
            {children}
            <Footer />
          </main>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 6):

change styles to do it:

```
drawerPaperClose: {
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    width: theme.spacing.unit * 7,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 9,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      width: 0,
      display:'none',
    },
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the styles of th **drawerClose** object.

**THE CODE IN THE [DOCUMENTATION](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer)**

```
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9) + 1,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(0) + 1,
    },
  },
```

The below is the new code, where you update the breakpoints by adding the **.down('sm')** method. Which modifies the styles for all screens below the specified **'sm'** breakpoints.

```
[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(0) + 1,
    },
```

**THE NEW UPDATED CODE:**

```
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9) + 1,
    },
    // New Code. 
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(0) + 1,
    },
  },
```