# React & MUI: Navigation on Mobile View

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I found an example of creating navigation with Drawer on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/zg0kjVl5b6Y) and have created a sandbox of the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hofstadter-rj4vn?file=/src/App.js

I need to maintain the two pane design for large(r) screens while for the mobile view, I need to display only one pane at a time:

- when the app is first loaded - show the menu
- when a link is clicked - show the content
- when the back button on the content page is clicked - show the menu

Web view:
[image]

Mobile view:

- show the menu by default:

[image]

- when a link is clicked, show content. User can click the `Back` button to return to the menu
  [image]

I note that I can set the Drawer's `open` value to true or false. But when I do this, there's still white space on the left side of the screen where the Drawer's supposed to be.

I found a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396360/how-to-hide-material-ui-mini-variant-drawer-on-mobile-view) to hide the Drawer on mobile screen, but this doesn't help me because I do need to show the Drawer when the app is first loaded, and then when a user clicks the back button on the content page.

How can I accomplish this? Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  Button,
  Drawer,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  Container,
  Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";

import HomeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Home";
import InfoIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Info";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  drawerPaper: { width: "inherit" },
  link: {
    textDecoration: "none",
    color: theme.palette.text.primary
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Router>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Drawer
          style={{ width: "220px" }}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
          open={true}
          classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
        >
          <List>
            <Link to="/" className={classes.link}>
              <ListItem button>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <HomeIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={"Home"} />
              </ListItem>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/about" className={classes.link}>
              <ListItem button>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <InfoIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={"About"} />
              </ListItem>
            </Link>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Container>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                className={classes.button}
                component={Link}
                to="/"
              >
                Back
              </Button>
              <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom>
                Home
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
                text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                Lorem Ipsum.
              </Typography>
            </Container>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/about">
            <Container>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                className={classes.button}
                component={Link}
                to="/"
              >
                Back
              </Button>
              <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom>
                About
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random
                text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from
                45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a
                Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
                one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem
                Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in
                classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem
                Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
                Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
                written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of
                ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of
                Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
                in section 1.10.32.
              </Typography>
            </Container>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example *in your question*.

Comment: @DrewReese I've included a link to sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hofstadter-rj4vn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Links tend to rot.... that sandbox can be updated or removed at any moment. The code you specifically have an issue with must be included in your question. This preserves it and makes for a more valuable and helpful question. People can search for and find it.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this, I've updated my question with the code.

Comment: So do you basically only need to display the navigation/drawer when only on your home path? Or does it need to be toggleable?

Comment: On mobile view, I need to display the navigation when on the home path. While on the web view (larger screens), need to show both the navigation and content all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Material-UI's `useMediaQuery` could help. Render your `Drawer` component in a `Route` on your home path (`"/"`) and conditionally set the `exact` prop if the route should match or not under certain media breakpoints.

Example:

```
...
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';

...

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const isMobileMatch = useMediaQuery("(max-width:600px)"); // <-- set breakpoint

  return (
    <Router>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Route exact={isMobileMatch} path="/"> // <-- conditionally match exactly
          <Drawer
            style={{ width: "220px" }}
            variant="persistent"
            anchor="left"
            open={true}
            classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
          >
            ...
          </Drawer>

        </Route>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Container>
              ...
            </Container>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/about">
            <Container>
              ...
            </Container>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-mui-navigation-on-mobile-view]

Play around with the iframe dimensions or the responsive view

Comment: Referring to <Route exact={!matches} path="/">, may I ask how this works? I've seen `exact` used to find an exact match to a route. But your line has an assignment?

Comment: @yogescicak `matches` returns a boolean value if the media query condition is met. This is pairing the media query condition to the exact match condition of the route's path matching. In other words, when the media query is true (the view is bigger than mobile) then the route path is matched exactly, otherwise for non-mobile views it is generally matched. I updated the code to match mobile views and renamed variables to hopefully make the relationship a little clearer.